# Find the words after the last symbol

Tags: google-sheets, regex

Any expert on Google Sheets Regular expressions? I am trying to extract all the text after the last two dots symbol found :

Example on the text=  **Roger : Blue Large : pack : high brand** the word that I need is high brand but I can find I way to match that pattern with the regex function.

Any help would be appreciated!

Feel free to make a copy out of the template below.[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-3ZZBar2BExaFhOMzpjpAbDFMTDmupuX4x0irwv3ixM/template/preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with this in B2:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,".+: (.+)")))
```

If you're afraid some time there could be no space after the two dots:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,".+:(.+)"))))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked perfectly!

Comment: I'm glad it was useful! Consider marking the question as answered 

Comment: hey Martin, could you help me once more with this one? I am still learning about Regex.  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/168825/how-would-you-find-and-extract-the-2nd-ocurrence-and-extract-only-the-number-tha