# How would you find and extract the 2nd ocurrence and extract only the number that is in between =value"123456789"?

Tags: google-sheets, regex, regexextract

Any expert on Google Sheets Regular expressions? I am trying to extract the numbers that exist in the second occurrence of this pattern value="400" from the HTML text that I am sharing in the link below. The number inside could have more digits. so I am trying to build a regex formula that first finds the second occurrence of the pattern and then extracts any numbers that are in between. Example value="any digits in here"

This is what I tried but it still brings everything =REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"(?i)(?:.*?value){2}")

Any help would be appreciated!

Feel free to make a copy out of the template below.

[enter link description here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-3ZZBar2BExaFhOMzpjpAbDFMTDmupuX4x0irwv3ixM/template/preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly not the most elegant way, but try with:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,".+value.+(value=\""\d+\"")")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly!